Ставится ли запятая перед помимо: главное, что _ помимо
Ставится ли запятая в предложении:
А главное, что помимо редких встреч, нас связывает одна общая идея.
Нужна ли запятая перед "помимо"?

Правильно:
А главное, что помимо редких встреч, нас связывает одна общая идея.
Пояснение
Правильность постановки запятой не вызывает сомнения: сочетание "а главное, что" воспринимается как устойчивое и часто используется. Примеры можно посмотреть в Карте слов.
Какова грамматика? Очевидно, в начале предложения находится вводное слово,  а затем изъяснительный союз ЧТО, относящийся ко всему предложению. Предложение начинается с предложного оборота (предлог помимо), поэтому запятой там нет.
